# Does JOIN or LEFT JOIN keep checking in a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, select

**I have a JOIN query but I need to optimize it for performance.**

For example, in this query:

```
"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :id"
```

Since there is no `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query, that select query will keep searching. If I add `LIMIT 1` to the end of that query, it will select only one and stop searching for more.

Here is my question and query:

```
"SELECT messages.text, users.name
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN users
ON messages.from_id = users.id
WHERE messages.user_id = :user_id"
```

In the `JOIN users ON messages.from_id = users.id` part, since there is only 1 user with that ID, will it keep searching after it has found that query? If it does, how can I optimize it so that it only searches for 1 row?

Comment: Does each user only have one message?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Each user can have many messages

Comment: Read a textbook re relational query implementation/optimization. Read everything in the manual re indexes & optimization including specifically join optimization. You should have done this before considering asking a question & related whatever remaining question you had to those. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :id
```

If there is no index on `id`, the entire table is scanned.

If there is a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` on `id`, only one row will be checked.

If there is a plain `INDEX`, it will scan from the first match until it finds an `id` that does not match.

For this:

```
SELECT  m.text, u.name
    FROM  messages AS m
    LEFT JOIN  users AS u  ON m.from_id = u.id
    WHERE  m.user_id = :user_id
```

It will do a "Nested Loop Join":

1. Find the occurrence(s) in `messages` that satisfy `m.user_id = :user_id` (see above).
2. For each such row, reach into `users` based on the `ON` clause.
3. There may be multiple rows (again, depending the index or lack of such).

So, your question "how can I optimize it so that it only searches for 1 row" is answered:

- If there can only be one row, declare it `UNIQUE`.
- If there are sometimes more than on, then `INDEX`.  But don't worry about checking for an extra row; it is not that costly.

You say "only 1 user with that ID", but fail to specify which id in which table.

But that is not the end of the story...

`LEFT JOIN` *may* get turned into `JOIN`.  In that case, `users` may be the first table to look at.  Note also that the Optimizer is smart enough to deduce that you want `u.id = :user_id`.  Anyway, the NLJ will start with `users`, then reach into `messages`.  Again, the types of indexes are important.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for *both* tables.  Then I can condense the answer to the relevant parts.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for confirmation of what I am saying.